# Does Code Definition Window (of Visual Studio 2022) support C# projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I read this on this article
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/whats-new-in-net-productivity-with-visual-studio-2022/

> The Code Definition Window now supports C# and Visual Basic allowing
> you to quickly understand and explore code. To use the Code Definition
> Window, select View > Window > Code Definition. Next, place your
> cursor on an identifier to navigate and explore code.

However, it doesn't work on my computer. The Code Definition Window simply shows "No definition selected". It works on a C++ project.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: I've tried and for me it's the same. For different C# projects it just writes "No definition selected". May be it's a bug, try to ask Microsoft on github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a Visual Studio 2022 version 17.1 Preview 1 feature

> NET Productivity
>
> - Go To Definition from source information in PDBs.
> - IntelliSense completion for await within an awaitable expression.
> - Move static members to a new type refactoring.
> - Simplify code to use the new C# 10.0 extended property patterns refactoring.
> - Detect variable swaps and suggest using a tuple to swap values refactoring.
> - Code definition window support for C# and Visual Basic.
> - ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-preview

Comment: just upgrated to 17.1 today. It works!

Comment: I updated but still the same message show, what am i missing. My version is 17.1.2

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.1.2 and it's still working for me. So, if you click, for example, on the name of a method at a call site, you still get the message?

Comment: Thanks for advice but i get still same "No definition selected" message. I tried on method or the services I called, nothing changed. I give up :)